# Function to resend otp not working in django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I have madefunction that resends otp when the 'resend Otp' lick is clicked. This is django project. The following are the codes that I wrote.

**html** (this page extends base.html)

```
<a class="resend-otp" href="#" onclick="ReSendOTP('{{user.username}}', 'resendOTPmess')" ><i id="resendOTPmess">Resend</i>OTP?</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'regd_ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

**js file**

```
function ReSendOTP(username, mess_id){
    mess = document.getElementById(mess_id);
    mess.innerText = "Sending...";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/user/resendOTP',
        data: {usr:username},
        success: function(data){
            mess.innerText = data;
        }
    })
}
```

**views.py**

```
def resend_otp(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        get_user = request.GET['usr']
        if User.objects.filter(username = get_user).exists() and not User.objects.get(username = get_user).is_active:
            user = User.objects.get(username=get_user)
            user_otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
            UserOtp.objects.create(user =  user, otp = user_otp)
            mess = f"Hello, {user.first_name}, \nYour OTP is {user_otp}\n Thanks!"
            
            send_mail(
                    "Welcome to Solve Litigation - Verify your Email",   #subject
                    mess,  #message
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,  # sender
                    [user.email],           #reciever
                    fail_silently= False
                )
            return HttpResponse("Resend")
    
    return HttpResponse("Can't Send OTP")
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import resend_otp
path('resendOTP', resend_otp)
```

So here I am requesting a resend otp for the **"username: rick.bhardwaj27@gmail.com"** but I am getting the follwing error in the console

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/resendOTP?usr=rick.bhardwaj27%40gmail.com 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `path('users/resendOTP', resend_otp)`?

Comment: @Musa, thank you for the help sir, I corrected that now it working fine.